# Scroll to particular component in Preact

Tags: preact

i am working on preact app and i have different components imported in a single page, i want to click on button in header and scroll to particular component.

this is my parent component

```
   <div class={style.root}>
    <Header />
    <Landing />
    <HowItWorks />
    <BrowserCatalogue />
    <ContactUs />
    <Footer />
  </div>
```

and in my header i have 3 buttons

```
  <div class={styles.headerItems}>
      <span style={styles.pointer}>Working</span>
      <span style={styles.pointer}>Catalogue</span>
      <span style={styles.pointer}>Contact</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

like when i click on working my page should scroll to HowItWorks component.any help?

Comment: Hi Rahul! Please check out my answer and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me help you friend. You should introduce `refs` in your parent component.
We will wrap each section in a `div` and give it a `ref` prop.

Here is sandbox for your reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-click-scroll-into-section-us8y7

### Parent Component

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Header from "./Header";
import HowItWorks from "./HowItWorks";
import BrowserCatalogue from "./BrowserCatalogue";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: null
    };
  }
  //refs
  howItWorks = React.createRef();
  browserCatalogue = React.createRef();

  changeSelection = index => {
    this.setState({
      selected: index
    });
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
      this.scrollToSection(this.state.selected);
  }

  scrollToSection = index => {
    let refs = [this.howItWorks, this.browserCatalogue];

    if (refs[index].current) {
      refs[index].current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "nearest"
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <Header changeSelection={this.changeSelection} />
        </div>
        <div ref={this.howItWorks}>
          <HowItWorks />
        </div>
        <div ref={this.browserCatalogue}>
          <BrowserCatalogue />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### Header

```
const Header = (props) => {
    const { changeSelection } = props;
    return (
      <div style={{ background: "green" }}>
        <span onClick={() => changeSelection(0)}>Working</span>{" "}
        <span onClick={() => changeSelection(1)}>Catalogue</span>{" "}
        <span>Contact</span>
      </div>
    );
}
```

**Workflow:**

- Each component gets a ref, and we keep that in memory for when we
  need to scroll.
- `Header`, we defined a handler in `parent` called `changeSelection()`
  and we pass it as prop. It takes an index and we use that index to
  update the parent state.
- Each link, "Working", "Catalogue", etc, will correspond to an `index`
  that matches with a `ref` in our `parent`, so setting up an `onClick()` handler for each `span` will allow us to pass in that index to `changeSelection()`
- `parent` state is updated, triggers `componentDidUpdate()`, in there
  we run `scrollToSection()` which you guessed it takes in an index (stored in our state as "selected"). Create an array of our refs, and simply use the matching index to locate that ref and scroll to that component.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome @RahulSyal! I hope you will integrate something like this in your app.